# Dynamic chat bubble using autolayout

Tags: autolayout

I am developing an application like **iMessage**.I would like to UI same like **iMessage** chat bubble work. I developed table view cell with auto layout.I have below table cell with UIImageView and UILabel.

[image]

UIImageView contain bubble image with `resizableImageWithCapInsets`. Right now everything is working fine except if text is small string then chat bubble is showing throughout the screen. so I would like to set constraints in such a way that my image view width will be according to label text. So if Label text is small then it will be small width image So it will be resizable according to width of label text. Any idea?

**Current output:**

[image].

Comment: Show constraints on uilabel. Don't give width constriant to label. Give same constraint to uiimageview with label

Comment: thanks Irfan I solved it. Sometimes I will post answer.

Comment: What was your solution. I think someone might get help So post it as well.

Comment: ok let me post it..I am composing

Comment: is it support multiline?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about my problem and researching on it and found below solutions. Posting it if it helps other.

So make it dynamic width based on text I put another blank label on right hand side and add constraints with it relative to left hand side controls(image view and label). Below is my  final layout of constraints. Then it's working as expected.

[image]

Output Screen shot :
[image]

Comment: i am facing problems in chat bubble design.need help

Comment: @susim Can you please share a demo project. It would help me to understand the constrain. Please..

Comment: @Sonu I had one but I have to find project and will publish in github